# Workday Function but return same date if it is an actual workday

Tags: excel

What excel code will return the 14th day of the month **if** it is a workday and then if it is not a workday, **then** return the next day that is a workday.

I can't get the workday function to work correctly, because whenever I use it, it doesn't seem to know how to handle that.

For Example:    10/14/2019 is a holiday

```
 =Workday (10/14/2019,0,hdays) = 10/14/2019  
 =Workday (10/14/2019,1,hdays) = 10/15/2019    =  desired solution since 10/14 is a holiday
```

however, if I have a date that is not a weekend or holiday, that middle variable of "1"
will add a day.

```
=Workday(11/14/2019,0,hdays) = 11/14/2019   = works here but not in example above.
=Workday(11/14/2019,1,hdays) = 11/15/2019   = wrong....I want 11/14
```

So I need the 14th if it is a workday, and if not, then I need the next workday.

Comment: @scott craner Brilliant!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Start with the day before and add `1`:

```
=Workday("10/14/2019"-1,1,hdays)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!